# Textbox allows numbers in a specific range - onkeypress onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a textbox that I want it to allow typing numbers from 0.00 to 24.00 only.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID = "txtHours" runat = "Server" 
onkeydown="limit(this,event);" 
onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);" 
MaxLength="5" Width = "40" text = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "Hours")%>'/>
```

I tried using Javascript in `onkeypress` and `onkeydown`

It's still allowing typing numbers like 25,26,25.01... etc

I want it not to even allow typing 5,6,7...etc after 2 is typed.

```
         function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
         var number = el.value.split('.');
         var numberbfr = el.value.split('.')[0];
         if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
             return false;
         }
         if (number.length > 1 && charCode == 46) {
             return false;
         }
         if (numberbfr.length > 1) {
             return false;
         }

         var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
         var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
         if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 1)) {
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }

     function getSelectionStart(o) {
         if (o.createTextRange) {
             var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
             r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
             if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
             return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
         } else return o.selectionStart
     }

     function limit(el, evt) {

         if (parseInt(el.value.charAt(0)) > 2 || (parseInt(el.value.charAt(0)) = 2 && parseInt(el.value.charAt(1)) > 4)) {
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Comment: could you please reproduce it in a fiddle or so..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Hope this solution will help you.Copy and paste below code.'stack' is the id of the textbox.

```
function checkOnlyZeroTo24(evt, el) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (el.value == '' && !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (el.value != '') {
        if (el.value.charAt(0) < 3 && charCode == 46 && el.value.length == 1 && el.value.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            document.getElementById('stack').setAttribute('maxlength', 4);
            return true;
        }
        else if (el.value.charAt(0) < 3 && !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && el.value.length == 1) {
            document.getElementById('stack').setAttribute('maxlength', 5);
            if (el.value.charAt(0) == 2 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 52))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else if (el.value <= 24 && el.value >= 10 && charCode == 46 && el.value.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            document.getElementById('stack').setAttribute('maxlength', 5);
            return true;
        }
        else if (el.value.substr(0, el.value.indexOf('.')) <= 24 && el.value.substr(0, el.value.indexOf('.')) >= 10 && el.value.charAt(2) == '.' && !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
            if (el.value.substr(0, el.value.indexOf('.')) == 24 && !(charCode == 48))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else if (el.value.charAt(0) < 3 && !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && el.value.charAt(1) == '.') {
            document.getElementById('stack').setAttribute('maxlength', 4);
            return true;
        }
        else if ((el.value.charAt(0) >= 3 && charCode == 46 && el.value.indexOf('.') == -1) || (el.value.charAt(1) == '.' && !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))) {
            document.getElementById('stack').setAttribute('maxlength', 4);

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Asp:TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID = "stack" runat = "server" onkeypress="return checkOnlyZeroTo24(event,this);"> </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this allows entering 25,26,27...29. Also, this allows 24.

Comment: It is not allowing entering 25,26,27...29. I have tested.

Comment: Could you tell me what it   text = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "Hours")%>' does?